# Remove whitespaces from json string "outside" key/values values

Tags: sql-server, json, trim

I have the following `json` string stored in a db field:

```
{"name" : "John Paul Mark", "surname" : "Johnson"}
```

note that `name` is composed by 3 different names, with a whitespace between them.

I need to trim the string removing the whitespaces between the `json` `key/values`, in order to get this final string:

```
{"name":"John Paul Mark","surname":"Johnson"}
```

leaving untouched the whitespaces **inside** the `key/values` values.

I tried to use a `Replace(@myString, ' ', '')` but it does not work as expected as it replaces **all** the whitespaces in the json string.

Any idea? Is there any native sql functionality that I could use instead of creating a custom function?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server/Oracle/Postgresql?

Comment: @lad2025 sql-server, tags updated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal solution (may fail when key/value itself contains `:` or `,`), but as workaround should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #tab(col)
VALUES ('{"name" : "John Paul Mark", "surname" : "Johnson"}');

SELECT col,
      [after_removing] = REPLACE(REPLACE(col, ' : ', ':'), ', ', ',')
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/416925)**</kbd>

Native JSON support will be available for [`SQL Server 2016`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Minifying JSON in a SQL Server query is such a common thing I want to do, but I have never found a good answer. I finally took the time to figure out a solution this week and came up with a pair of useful SQL functions at the end of this post.

The first function uses a recursive CTE with openjson() to flatten JSON to a table of key-value pairs from all depths of the JSON. This allows the second function to easily compare before and after each change to see if a JSON value was accidentally modified.

The second function does the minification. It cursors over a set of chars to be removed, then walks the string for each occurrence found to test the removal and compare the result to the original to ensure the change is safe before keeping the change.

In this example you can see the line breaks and whitespace are removed without affecting a value that happens to have content that resembles JSON structure but isn't actually JSON:

```
declare @json varchar(max) = '{
    "test": "testing   {   internal   [   ] tokens   }  ",
    "test2": [  "test-val"  ]   ,
    "test3": 123
}'

select dbo.json_minify(@json) as minified

--> {"test":"testing   {   internal   [   ] tokens   }","test2":["test-val"],"test3":123}
```

If you're curious about the flattening output, run this query for any json content:

```
select * from dbo.json_flatten(@json) where intermediate = 0 order by path
```

Remove the filter on `intermediate = 0` to see the rows for intermediate values. It is normal to exclude them but sometimes useful to see them when debugging.

I won't make any guarantees, but it appears to be working well for the cases I have tested and the speed has been ok for my small sets. For efficiency with large sets you'd probably want to run it as part of a cleanup rather than on the fly for large output.

I welcome ideas for improvement and any comments about how it performs if you choose to use it.

```
create or alter function dbo.json_flatten(
    @json varchar(max)
) returns table as
    /*  
        Created by Keith Townsend on 3/19/2024

        Recursive CTE to flatten nested JSON up to depth 100

        - Intermediate column is useful for omitting rows that aren't the final property in a chain.
        - Path column is compatible with sql json functions that use path.
        - Stub column is useful for finding all array items at same property chain for aggregation.
          It is like path column but without any indexes inside the square brackets.

        NOTE: custom function dbo.json_minify() depends on this function.
    */

    return 
        with data as (
            select  --> cast & collate required in anchor to match openjson() types in recursive part
                    path     = cast('$' as nvarchar(4000))  collate Latin1_General_BIN2, 
                    stub     = cast('$' as nvarchar(4000)) collate Latin1_General_BIN2,
                    [key]    = cast('$' as nvarchar(4000))  collate Latin1_General_BIN2, 
                    value    = cast(@json as nvarchar(max)) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
                    typenum  = cast(typenum as tinyint),
                    depth    = 0
            from    (select case 
                        --> detect what type of JSON value we were given (match openjson type numbers)
                        when @json is null then 0
                        when 1 = isnumeric(@json) then 2
                        when @json in ('true', 'false') then 3
                        when 1 = isjson(@json) and left(trim(@json), 1) = '[' then 4
                        when 1 = isjson(@json) and left(trim(@json), 1) = '{' then 5
                        else 1
                    end) x(typenum)
            union all
            select  case x.typenum
                        when 4 then concat(x.path, '[', j.[key], ']') --> array
                        else concat(x.path, '.', j.[key])             --> property
                    end, 
                    case x.typenum
                        when 4 then concat(x.[stub], '[]')           --> array
                        else concat(x.[stub], '.', j.[key])          --> property
                    end, 
                    j.[key], j.value, j.type,
                    x.depth + 1
            from    data x 
                    outer apply openjson(case when 1 = isjson(x.value) then x.value end) j 
            where   j.type > 0
                    and depth < 100
        ), types(id,name) as (
            -- order matters to align index with type numbers returned by openjson()
            select [key], value from openjson('["null","string","number","bool","array","object"]')
        )
            select  d.path, d.stub, d.[key], d.value, d.typenum, 
                    typename = t.name,            --> readable json type
                    intermediate = isJson(value), --> caller can omit intermediate rows (typical)
                    d.depth
            from    data d 
                    left join types t 
                        on t.id = d.typenum
GO

create or alter function dbo.json_minify(
    @value varchar(max)
) returns varchar(max) as
    begin
        /*
            Created by Keith Townsend on 3/19/2024

            Minifies nonessential whitespace in JSON string. 
            NOTE: depends on custom function dbo.json_flatten() to help detect value changes at any depth
        */

        -- copy orignal value to our manipulation variable
        declare @target varchar(max) = @value

        -- pregenerate flat values for original JSON to compare with during loop
        declare @flatvalue table(path nvarchar(4000) collate Latin1_General_BIN2, value nvarchar(max) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
        insert @flatvalue select path, value from dbo.json_flatten(@value) where intermediate = 0

        -- enumerate the tokens to remove
        declare @toremove char(1)
        declare csr cursor for select value from openjson('["\t","\r","\n"," "]')
        open csr
        fetch next from csr into @toremove
        while @@fetch_status = 0
        begin

            -- walk the string and remove current token unless is alters a value
            declare @pos int = charindex(@toremove, @target)
            while @pos > 0 and @pos < len(@target) --> check length because over will search from beginning and cause infinite loop if any value has the token
            begin

                -- remove the token
                declare @temp varchar(max) = stuff(@target, @pos, 1, '')

                -- ensure we didn't affect a value before we accept the modification
                -- we are using our dbo.json_flatten() function to ensure we compare all depths
                if exists (
                    select  *
                    from    (select path, value from dbo.json_flatten(@temp) where intermediate = 0) x1 
                            full outer join @flatvalue x2 
                                on x1.[path] = x2.[path] 
                                and x1.value = x2.value 
                    where   x1.[path] is null 
                            or x2.[path] is null
                )
                    set @pos = @pos + 1 --> skip over current position for next charindex
                else
                    set @target = @temp --> keep the change

                -- find next token
                set @pos = charindex(@toremove, @target, @pos)
            end

            fetch next from csr into @toremove
        end

        return @target
    end
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in MySql in case there is no ':' or "," in the key/value

```
create table json_array (json varchar(1000));
insert into json_array(json) values('{"name" : "John Paul Mark", "surname" : "Johnson"}');
select concat(concat(concat(concat(trim(substr(json, 1, locate(':', json)-1)),':'), concat(trim(substr(json, locate(':', json)+1, locate(',',json)-locate(':' , json)-1 ) ),',')), concat(trim(substr(json, locate(',', json)+1, locate(':',json, locate(':', json)+1)-locate(',', json)-1 ) ),':')), trim(substr(json, locate(':', json, locate(':', json)+1)+1))) as output from json_array;
```